# @Viewscoped bean is not destroyed when navigate to another page

Tags: spring, jsf, backing-beans

I'm using `@Viewscoped` beans in a JSF 2.1 project. The strange thing is that when I first get a page the bean is clearly initialized with all the initial parameters. But when I navigate away, to another page, even if I close the browser tab where te app is open the bean does not die. When I go back to the page that use this bean the values are the same that were modified during the utilization of this page. And more, if I open another browser like IE or Chrome, the values are still there too!!
Is behaving like a sessionscoped. Or somekind of inmortal bean , je.

The bean is annotated like this.

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped

public class MyBean {
  //the rest of the code.
}
```

Why this is happen? Could be springframework annotation the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was my spring annotation in the bean. I use `@Controller` from Spring Framework. This annotation create a Singleton, so my backing bean, even it has `@ManagedBean` and `@ViewScoped`, was created only once, and was never destroyed a re-created in every view.
I deleted `@Controller` and replace `@Autowired` for `@ManagedProperty` for the injection and now everything works as expected.

The answer in this [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483115/data-from-requestscoped-bean-is-cached) help to figure out

Answer (score -2):

Define your Bean using this anotations

```
@ViewScoped
public @Named class MyBean
```

`@PreDestroy` works well.