# Spring JSF integration: how to manage a bean and inject a Spring component/service?

Tags: spring, jsf, dependency-injection, integration, managed-bean

I understand that a managed bean works like a controller, because your only task is "link" the View Layer with Model.

To use a bean as a managed bean I must declare `@ManagedBean`annotation, doing that I can communicate JSF with bean directly.

If I want to inject some component (from Spring) in this managedBean I have two possibles ways:

1. Choose the property in ManagedBean (like "BasicDAO dao") and declare `@ManagedProperty(#{"basicDAO"})` above the property. Doing it, i'm injecting the bean `"basicDAO"` from Spring in ManagedBean.
2. Declared @Controller in ManagedBean Class, then i'll have `@ManagedBean` and `@Controller` annotations, all together. And in property `"BasicDAO dao"` i must use `@Autowired` from Spring.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is another way to use Spring-managed beans in JSF-managed beans by simply extending your JSF bean from `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` and Spring will handle the dependency injection.

```
@ManagedBean // JSF-managed.
@ViewScoped // JSF-managed scope.
public class GoodBean extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {

    @Autowired
    private SpringBeanClass springBeanName; // No setter required.

    // springBeanName is now available.
}
```

Comment: I know `@ManagedBean` is ***DEPRECATED*** in JSF. But as you see the questioner mentions `@ManagedBean` in the question and again as you see "54 upvoted answer" mentions about `@ManagedBean` as well. And again as you see, I started my answer by saying "There is another way". Honestly, I didn't thought that my answer would be the accepted one instead of @BalusC's excellent answer. I just wanted to show another easier way. I don't understand how could I deserve those "I'm almost inclined to downvote" words :) "same person that asked the question?" lol, no :D Have you ever tried that before? :)

Answer (score 105):

### `@Named`/`@ManagedBean` vs `@Controller`/`@Component`

First of all, you should choose **one** framework to manage your beans. You should choose either CDI/JSF or Spring to manage your beans. Whilst the following example works, it is fundamentally wrong:

```java
@Named // CDI-managed (same applies to @ManagedBean)
@Controller // Spring-managed (same applies to @Component)
public class BadBean {}
```

You end up with **two** completely separate instances of the very same managed bean class, one managed by CDI (or JSF) and another one managed by Spring. It's not directly clear which one would *actually* be used in EL when you reference it as `#{someBean}`. If you have the [`SpringBeanFacesELResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/jsf/el/SpringBeanFacesELResolver.html) registered in `faces-config.xml`, then it would be the Spring-managed one, not the CDI/JSF-managed one. If you don't have that, then it would be the CDI/JSF-managed one.

Also, when you declare a JSF managed bean specific scope, such as `@ViewScoped` or `@FlowScoped` from `jakarta.faces.*` package, then it will only be recognized and used by `@Named`/`@ManagedBean`. It won't be understood by `@Controller`/`@Component` as it expects its own `@Scope` annotation. The Spring scope defaults to singleton (application scope) when absent.

```java
@Named // CDI-managed.
@ViewScoped // JSF-specific scope.
@Controller // Spring-managed (without own scope, so actually becomes a singleton).
public class BadBean {}
```

When you reference the above bean via `#{someBean}`, it would return the Spring-managed application scoped bean, not the CDI/JSF-managed view scoped bean.

---

### `@ManagedProperty` vs `@Autowired`

The JSF-specific `@jakarta.faces.annotation.ManagedProperty` works only in CDI/JSF-managed beans, i.e. when you're using `@Named`/`@ManagedBean`. The Spring-specific `@Autowired` works only in Spring-managed beans, i.e. when you're using `@Controller`/`@Component`. Below approaches are less or more equivalent and cannot be mixed:

```java
@Named // CDI-managed.
@RequestScoped // CDI-managed scope.
public class GoodBean {

    @Inject @ManagedProperty("#{springBeanName}")
    private SpringBeanClass springBeanName;
}
```

```java
@Component // Spring-managed.
@Scope("request") // Spring-managed scope.
public class GoodBean {

    @Autowired
    private SpringBeanClass springBeanName;
}
```

Do note that when you have the [`SpringBeanFacesELResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/jsf/el/SpringBeanFacesELResolver.html) registered in `faces-config.xml` as per the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/jsf/el/SpringBeanFacesELResolver.html),

```xml
<application>
    ...
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

and thus you can reference Spring managed beans in EL via `#{springBeanName}`, then you can just reference them in `@ManagedProperty` too, as it basically sets the evaluated result of the given EL expression. In order to get `@Inject` to work with Faces implicit objects you only need a `@ApplicationScoped @FacesConfig` annotated class in the project in order to auto-activate it.

```java
@FacesConfig
@ApplicationScoped
public class FacesConfiguration {}
```

The other way round, injecting a CDI/JSF-managed bean via `@Autowired`, is in no way supported. You can however use `@Autowired` in a CDI/JSF managed bean when you extend your bean from [`SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html). This will automatically register the CDI/JSF-managed bean instance in Spring autowirable context during constructor invocation, which means that everything `@Autowired` will be available in `@PostConstruct` and later.

```java
@Named // CDI-managed.
@ViewScoped // JSF-specific scope.
public class GoodBean extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements Serializable {
 
    @Autowired
    private SpringBeanClass springBeanName;
 
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        // springBeanName is now available.
    }
}
```

Or when your architecture doesn't allow extending beans from a different base class, then you can always manually register the JSF managed bean instance in Spring autowirable context as below. See also [How to integrate JSF 2 and Spring 3 (or Spring 4) nicely](https://www.beyondjava.net/blog/integrate-jsf-2-spring-3-nicely/) for the trick.

```java
@Named // CDI-managed.
@ViewScoped // JSF-specific scope.
public class GoodBean implements Serializable {
 
    @Autowired
    private SpringBeanClass springBeanName;
 
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        FacesContextUtils
            .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance())
            .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);

        // springBeanName is now available.
    }
}
```

### Transparently using `@Autowired` in `@Named`

Or if you don't want to do any of this manually, then consider using a CDI extension as described in this blog [Using OmniFaces CDI @ViewScoped with unload/destroy in a Spring Boot project](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2023/11/using-omnifaces-cdi-viewscoped-with.html):

```java
public class SpringAutowiredExtension implements Extension {

    private Map<Class<?>, String> autowiredFields = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public <T> void processAnnotatedType(@Observes @WithAnnotations(Named.class) ProcessAnnotatedType<T> processAnnotatedType, BeanManager beanManager) {
        Class<T> beanClass = processAnnotatedType.getAnnotatedType().getJavaClass();

        if (!beanClass.getPackage().getName().startsWith(YourSpringConfiguration.BEANS_PACKAGE)) {
            return; // This should filter out any CDI managed beans provided by e.g. Faces and OmniFaces themselves.
        }

        processAnnotatedType.configureAnnotatedType()
            .filterFields(field -> field.isAnnotationPresent(Autowired.class))
            .forEach(this::registerAutowiredField);
    }

    private void registerAutowiredField(AnnotatedFieldConfigurator<?> fieldConfigurator) {
        fieldConfigurator.add(InjectLiteral.INSTANCE);
        Field field = fieldConfigurator.getAnnotated().getJavaMember();
        autowiredFields.put(field.getType(), field.getName());
    }

    public void afterBeanDiscovery(@Observes AfterBeanDiscovery event) {
        autowiredFields.entrySet().forEach(autowiredField -> injectBeanViaSpringContext(event, autowiredField.getKey(), autowiredField.getValue()));
    }

    private static void injectBeanViaSpringContext(AfterBeanDiscovery event, Class<?> type, String name) {
        event.addBean().addType(type).createWith(ignoreCdiContext -> getBeanFromSpringContext(type, name));
    }

    private static Object getBeanFromSpringContext(Class<?> type, String name) {
        try {
            try {
                return Spring.getContext().getBean(type);
            }
            catch (NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException ignore) {
                return Spring.getContext().getBean(name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot get bean from Spring context", e);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can transparently use `@Autowired` in `@Named` beans without the need to extend from some Spring-specific super class, or to manually grab the bean from Spring context via some Spring-specific helper class.

```java
@Named // CDI-managed.
@ViewScoped // JSF-specific scope.
public class GoodBean implements Serializable {
 
    @Autowired
    private SpringBeanClass springBeanName;
 
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        // springBeanName is now available.
    }
}
```

---

### `@XxxScoped` vs `@Scope`

Spring's `@Scope` has limited support for JSF scopes. There's no equivalent for JSF's `@ViewScoped`. You'd basically either homegrow your own scopes, or stick to manually registering the JSF managed bean instance in Spring autowirable context as shown above.

And, from the other side on, Spring WebFlow was taken over in JSF 2.2 via new `@FlowScoped` annotation. So if you happen to be on JSF 2.2 already, then you don't necessarily need to use Spring WebFlow if you solely want the flow scope.

In case you're using Spring Boot, then you can use [JoinFaces](https://joinfaces.org/). It has already ported the JSF `@ViewScoped` into the Spring scope. It only hasn't ported the OmniFaces `@ViewScoped` into the Spring scope. For this, head to the aforementioned blog [Using OmniFaces CDI @ViewScoped with unload/destroy in a Spring Boot project](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2023/11/using-omnifaces-cdi-viewscoped-with.html).

#### See also:

- [When is it necessary or convenient to use Spring or EJB3 or all of them together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369356/when-is-it-necessary-or-convenient-to-use-springjsf2-or-ejb3jsf2-or-all-of-the/)
- [JSF Service Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011392/jsf-service-layer/)
- [Backing beans (@ManagedBean) or CDI Beans (@Named)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named/4347707#4347707)
- [Using JSF as view technology of Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744910/using-jsf-as-view-technology-of-spring-mvc)
- [How to install and use CDI on Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995951/how-to-install-and-use-cdi-on-tomcat)

Comment: You said: "JSF-specific @ ManagedProperty works only in JSF-managed beans, i.e. when you're using @ ManagedBean". But i'm using @ ManagedProperty to refence a Spring-Bean and this is works fine. How i said: I'm using @ ManagedProperty(#{'basicDAO'}) and bean 'basicDAO' is a @ Repository bean.

Comment: @ ManagedProperty is the approach(which i've come across) to integrate spring with jsf(inject bean). what I believe(correct me if I'm wrong) org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver propagates jsf bean to Spring Bean. And Generally we create Spring container(org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener) which constitutes jsf. And as @BalusC said as of now Spring doesn't support Java EE 6 CDI. I dearly wanted @ ConversationalScope which is not supported by spring container having JSF.

Comment: So, ManagedProperty is like @Autowired, but in JSF. :D

Comment: A 54 upvoted answer replaced as the accepted one by a new one that refers to deprecated annotations... Wow...

Comment: @BalusC on the MVC concept, you see the JSF Managed bean as a View or a Controller?

Comment: @BalusC: In the first paragraph in **CDI - trying to unify it all** the _but `@Inject` works inside a `@ManagedBean`_ is most likely a typo? Or I've learned something new.

Comment: @Kukeltje: Not a typo. The `@Inject` can be used inside a `@ManagedBean` to inject a CDI bean or an EJB. In hindsight, it might have been Mojarra specific, not JSF API specific.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is via XML. I used `@Component` in already made jsf managed bean but `@Autowired` did not work because managed bean was already there in faces-config.xml. If it is mandatory to keep that managed bean definition along with its managed property in the xml file then it is suggested to add the spring bean as another managed property inside the managed bean tag. Here the spring bean is there defined in spring-config.xml(can be autowired somewhere alternately). please refer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19904591/5620851

edited by me. I suggest to either implement it altogether through annotation @Managed and @Component or via xml for both.

Answer (score 0):

You can autowire individual beans without `@Autowired` by leveraging `getBean` of the current WebApplication context.

Please refer to @BalusC's answer for more details. This is just a slight modification over his example:

```java
@ManagedBean // JSF-managed.
@ViewScoped // JSF-managed scope.
public class GoodBean implements Serializable {

    // @Autowired // No Autowired required
    private SpringBeanClass springBeanName; // No setter required.

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        WebApplicationContext ctx = FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        this.springBeanName = ctx.getBean(SpringBeanClass.class);
        // springBeanName is now available.
    }
}
```