# EL resolver in faces-config.xml

Tags: spring, jsf, el, faces-config

While working on a Spring-JSF integration, I'm seeing this entry in `faces-config.xml`.

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>
```

Can someone explain what exactly `<application>` and `<el-resolver>` are?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`<application>` represents the [JSF application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html). Exactly the one as you can obtain as

```
Application application = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
```

`<el-resolver>` represents the [EL resolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html) as [used by JSF application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#getELResolver()). Exactly the one as you can obtain as

```
ELResolver elResolver = application.getELResolver();
```

What exactly they in turn do can just be read in their javadocs which I've linked above. In a nutshell, the `Application` basically represents the application-wide JSF configuration and the `ELResolver` is responsible for evaluating EL expressions in form of `#{...}`.

In case of `SpringBeanFacesELResolver`, it decorates the underlying EL resolver to recognize Spring managed beans as well based on Spring's own application context and configuration files. In other words, you'll this way be able to use Spring managed beans in JSF pages via EL.

#### See also:

- [Spring JSF integration: how to inject a Spring component/service in JSF managed bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387993/spring-jsf-integration-how-to-inject-a-spring-component-service-in-jsf-managed/18388289#18388289)

Comment: thanks @BalusC you  have been very helpful to new JSF developers like m who are struggle to find decent tutorials to know about the basics of JSF i also have the following doubts            1) what is external context when it should be used and how sessions are handled in JSF