# How to inject some objects with @Autowired and integrate them with JSF

Tags: spring, jsf, service, javabeans, autowired

I am trying to integrate Spring with JSF.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SomeBean() implements Serializable{

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;   // with get and set
...
    @PostConstruct
public void init() {
      FacesContextUtils
    .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance())
    .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this.someService);
}

}

@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService{

    @Autowired
    SomeDao someDao;
...
}
```

I always get null the someService from bean; it does not inject any value.
This is the error that returns us:

javax.servlet.ServletException: JBAS011048: No logró construir la instancia del componente
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606).

Can anyone please tell me how to do this properly.Thanks in advance.

we rely on the following Links:
[Spring JSF integration: how to inject a Spring component/service in JSF managed bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387993/spring-jsf-integration-how-to-inject-a-spring-component-service-in-jsf-managed)

[@Autowired Spring service not injected in a managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553945/autowired-spring-service-not-injected-in-a-managed-bean)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this post](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/) in order to integrate spring with JSF.

Comment: Hi olexd. In fact I already implement the solution as suggested in the link you sent me, in section: Spring Annotations. I did the same but I have one error which is that is not injecting:                                @Autowired
 UserBo userBo;

 public void setUserBo(UserBo userBo) {
  this.userBo = userBo;
 }

 public String printMsgFromSpring() {
  return userBo.getMessage();
 }                                                                                                            There is no exception thrown but its value is null. Do you know why this is happening? Thanks in advance.