# when injecting Spring service bean to JSF ManagedBean it shows me a NullPointerException

Tags: spring, jsf, dependency-injection

Tomcat 8 ,JSF , Spring
When i try to inject a spring service to jsf managed bean it shows the NullPointerException

**check.xhtml**

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"

          >

      <h:head>        </h:head>

      <h:body>

      <p:dataTable var="check" value="#{checkBean.checks}">
        <p:column headerText="Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{check.name}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="URL">
            <h:outputText value="#{check.url}" />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>

      </h:body>  
     </html>
```

**CheckBean**

```
 @Setter
    @ManagedBean
    public class CheckBean implements Serializable {


        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

          @ManagedProperty("#{checkService}")
          private CheckService checkService;


        private List<Check> checks;

        private Check check = new Check();

        public void save()
        {   

            checkService.save(check);       
        }


        public List<Check> getChecks() {

            System.out.println(checkService==null);
            //checks=checkService.findAll();
            return checks;
        }
        }
```

**CheckService**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Service
public class CheckService implements CheckServiceInterface {


    @Autowired
    private CheckRepository checkRepository;



    public List<Check> findAll()
    {
        //return checkRepository.findAll();
        List<Check> l=new ArrayList<Check>();
        Check c =new Check();
        c.setName("aa");
        c.setUrl("www.exemple.com");
        l.add(c);
        return l;


    }


    public void save(Check check) {

        checkRepository.save(check);

    }
}
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

 <application>

         <el-resolver>
                org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver> 

</application>
</faces-config>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 <display-name>Crud</display-name>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
  <param-value>0</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
 </listener>


<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>selectChecks.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>



</web-app>
```

**SpringConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.crud.repositories")
public class SpringConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test");
        ds.setUsername("crud");
        ds.setPassword("crud");
        return ds;
    }



    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("com.crud.entities");
        return lef;
    }



    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }

}
```

**MyWebAppInitializer**

public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext=new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(SpringConfiguration.class);


    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

}
```

}

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>CrudTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>Crud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>

        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--********************************************************************************************** -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1-b04</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>





        <!--********************************************************************************************** -->

    </dependencies>



    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframewok</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                <type>bom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <build>
        <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Instead of posting the entire code of your application, can't you narrow it down first? For instance, let's start with the log trace, the bean where the exception occurs and the one you're trying to inject?

Comment: Lets start with searching for duplicates or related posts to...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387993/spring-jsf-integration-how-to-inject-a-spring-component-service-in-jsf-managed

Comment: i'm trying to inject the checkService into ChekBean. thank you

Comment: mars 04, 2016 11:15:44 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/selectChecks.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /selectChecks.xhtml @14,56 value="#{checkBean.checks}": Error reading 'checks' on type com.crud.managedbeans.CheckBean
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(Unknown Source)