# Spring JSF 2.3 Integration

Tags: spring, jsf-2.3

In lieu of JSF 2.3+ greater coupling with CDI, will Spring integrate with JSF 2.3, and if so any timeline on this?

It appears there are still issue with JSF 2.2 ViewScope.

Comment: Spring itself already (partially) implements CDI. Your question is in its current form technically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18387993

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring JSF integration: how to inject a Spring component/service in JSF managed bean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387993/spring-jsf-integration-how-to-inject-a-spring-component-service-in-jsf-managed)

Comment: JSF 2.3 is not out yet, it's going to be part of Java EE 8 which is not out yet. It will take time before Java EE 8 is released, and it will most likely not be before the second half of 2017. So it will take at least about one year before you can expect explicit support for this in Spring.