# How to integrate OmniFaces with Spring Boot

Tags: jsf, spring-boot, integration, omnifaces

I've found some tutorials about integrating JSF technology with Spring Boot, but it seems a rather involved work to get OmniFaces working with Spring Boot. Is it a good idea to integrate these two together at all?

Comment: I've got the latest omnifaces 1.x version working with JSF 2.2 in a Spring Boot project. I believe the real integration relates to make JSF work in Spring Boot (which is couple of steps), not omnifaces. The reason why I keep with the 1.x branch is that it fulfills my requirements and doesn't require CDI.

Comment: @XtremeBiker: I didn't know that omnifaces 1.x version does not require CDI. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OmniFaces is provided via [JoinFaces](http://joinfaces.org/).

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>omnifaces-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>5.x.x</version>
</dependency>
```

Or when you're still on Spring Boot 2.x:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>omnifaces3-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>4.x.x</version>
</dependency>
```

In case you're primarily intertested in OmniFaces `@ViewScoped`, then you really need `@Named` instead of `@Component` in order to fully utilize its powers. And in order to be able to inject existing Spring managed beans via `@Autowired` into those `@Named` beans without any additional fuzz, you might want to install a CDI extension as described in this blog [Using OmniFaces CDI @ViewScoped with unload/destroy in a Spring Boot project](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2023/11/using-omnifaces-cdi-viewscoped-with.html).

#### See also:

- [Spring JSF integration: how to manage a bean and inject a Spring component/service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387993/spring-jsf-integration-how-to-manage-a-bean-and-inject-a-spring-component-servi)