# WebSocket <o:socket> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException in Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, websocket, omnifaces, jsf-2.3

I try recreating the demo example in omnifaces https://showcase.omnifaces.org/push/socket

Tomcat throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException with the following stacktrace

```
28-Dec-2021 17:29:41.969 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/ms-app] threw exception [Error creating bean with name 'alertUsers': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.ms.webapp.action.alertUsers.setPush(org.omnifaces.cdi.PushContext); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.omnifaces.cdi.PushContext] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}] with root cause
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.omnifaces.cdi.PushContext] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:553)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.el.SpringBeanELResolver.getValue(SpringBeanELResolver.java:55)
            at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:180)
            at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:208)
            at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:94)
            at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
            at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
            at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:258)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:86)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:83)
            at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:307)
            at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:114)
            at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:918)
            at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1905)
            at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1908)
            at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1908)
            at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:491)
            at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:194)
            at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
            at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:151)
            at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:151)
            at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.renderView(OmniViewHandler.java:115)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:126)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:223)
            at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:89)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at com.ms.webapp.filter.MessageFilter.doFilter(MessageFilter.java:44)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
            at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
            at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:713)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:462)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:387)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:315)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:150)
            at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:286)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy207.forward(Unknown Source)
            at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
            at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
            at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
            at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
            at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at com.ms.webapp.filter.LocaleFilter.doFilterInternal(LocaleFilter.java:67)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:201)
            at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:305)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1626)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have installed Weld in Tomcat with balusC tutorial here https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html

xhtml snippet

```
<h3>Global counter</h3>
<p>
    Below is a static counter which has the same value application wide.
</p>

<h1><h:panelGroup id="count">#{alertUsers.count}</h:panelGroup></h1>

<h:form>
    <p>
        If you enable the push, then a websocket will be opened.
        Note that it's by default always auto-connected when included in the page, but for demo purposes we're initially disabling it.
    </p>
    <p>
        <h:panelGroup id="toggle">
            Push is #{alertUsers.connected ? 'connected' : 'disconnected'} 
            <h:commandButton value="#{alertUsers.connected ? 'disconnect' : 'connect'} it" action="#{alertUsers.toggle}">
                <f:ajax render="toggle increment :count"/>
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </p>
    <p>
        If push is connected and you press the "increment!" button, then the static counter will increment in bean and the push will send out the new value to the same channel in all connected clients.
        To see it yourself, open the same page in multiple tabs/windows/browsers/machines and trigger the push in only one of it.
        Note that the counter also won't increment from other side if push is still disconnected on current page.
    </p>
    <p>
        <h:commandButton id="increment" value="increment!" action="#{alertUsers.increment}" disabled="#{not alertUsers.connected}">
            <f:ajax />
        </h:commandButton>
    </p>
</h:form>


<!-- NOTE: having inline script in XHTML like below is bad practice. -->
<!-- It's included directly in XHTML just for sake of demo. -->
<!-- In real world code, put it in a JS file :) -->

<script>
    function updateCounter(newvalue) {
        $("#count").text(newvalue);
    }

    function onclosePush(code) {
        if (code == -1) {
            alert("Oops! Your browser doesn't seem to support web sockets. The push functionality won't work.")
        }
        else if (code != 1000) {
            alert("Oops! Push has stopped working with error code " + code + "! Reload the page.")
        }
    }
</script>

<!-- End of bad practice ;) -->


<o:socket channel="counter" onmessage="updateCounter" onclose="onclosePush" connected="#{alertUsers.connected}" />
```

alertUsers.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.omnifaces.cdi.Push;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.PushContext;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;

@Named("alertUsers")
@ViewScoped
public class alertUsers implements Serializable {

    private static AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    private boolean connected;

    @Inject @Push(channel="counter")
    private PushContext push;

    public void toggle() {
        connected = !connected;
    }

    public void increment() {
        long newvalue = counter.incrementAndGet();
        push.send(newvalue);
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return connected;
    }

    public Long getCount() {
        return counter.get();
    }

}
```

Maven-spring compiles it fine, but when i throw the jar in WEB/lib,Tomcat localhost throws the above Exception.
My current guess is that i cant use Inject in an omnifaces.cdi.PushContext. Do i need to define the bean specifically? How?

As an Aside if i use com.google.inject.Inject instead of javax.inject.Inject, Tomcat doesn't throw the above error but the counter does not get autoupdated and the connection is closed with onclosePush function and 1008 error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone needs this. I have decided to give up with Omnifaces-Spring because it is incompatible as others have suggested. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41416546/how-to-integrate-omnifaces-with-spring-boot)