# Need solution please how to solve this error?

Tags: spring, jsf, nullpointerexception, autowired

I'm using primefaces spring and JSF and when i call a method from the my bean 
it retrieves the properties from the view but when it arrives to the methods of my service to make the insertion in the data database by calling the dao method this error appears

```
==============> begin 
Nom ==>Charafi
prenom ==>Saad
telephone ==>0622036006
MAT ==>A885511
DAte ==>Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017
mail ==>mrsaad.charafi@gmail.com
==============> end 
mars 18, 2017 12:14:45 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute      
Avertissement: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:292)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
at     javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.primefaces.barcelona.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:32)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at ma.controle.gestion.bean.RessourceBean.save(RessourceBean.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:279)
... 34 more

mars 18, 2017 12:14:45 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl  handlePartialResponseError
Grave: java.lang.NullPointerException
at ma.controle.gestion.bean.RessourceBean.save(RessourceBean.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:279)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.primefaces.barcelona.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:32)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

here is my view

```
          <h:form>       
      <div class="ui-g">
        <div class="ui-g-12">
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Create</h3>


                         <p:panelGrid columns="4" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-4,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-4" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group" style="border:0px none; background-color:transparent;">
                            <p:outputLabel for="nom" value="Nom"/>
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                                <p:inputText id="nom" value="#{ressourceBean.ressource.nom}" />
                                <label>nom</label>
                            </h:panelGroup>

                            <p:outputLabel for="mail" value="Mail"/>
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                                <p:inputText id="mail" value="#{ressourceBean.ressource.mail}"/>
                                <label>Mail</label>
                            </h:panelGroup>



                            <p:outputLabel for="prenom" value="Prenom"/>
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                                <p:inputText id="prenom" value="#{ressourceBean.ressource.prenom}"/>
                                <label>prenon</label>
                            </h:panelGroup>

                            <p:outputLabel for="telephone" value="Telephone"/>
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                                <p:inputText id="telephone" value="#{ressourceBean.ressource.telephone}"/>
                                <label>Telephone</label>
                            </h:panelGroup>


                            <p:outputLabel for="matricule" value="Matricule"/>
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                                <p:inputText id="matricule" value="#{ressourceBean.ressource.matricule}"/>
                                <label>Matricule</label>
                            </h:panelGroup>



                            <p:outputLabel for="dateEntree" value="Date d'entree"/>
                            <p:calendar id="dateEntree" value="#{ressourceBean.ressource.dateEntree}"/>




                            </p:panelGrid>

                                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-save" actionListener="#{ressourceBean.save}" value="Save" style="display:inline-block;margin-top:5px"/>


               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </h:form>
```

and here is my bean RessourceBean

```
package ma.controle.gestion.bean;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import ma.controle.gestion.modele.Ressource;
import ma.controle.gestion.service.IRessourceService;

@ManagedBean(name="ressourceBean")
@ViewScoped
public class RessourceBean implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String nom;
private String prenom;
private String matricule;
private String mail;
private String telephone;
private Date dateEntree;

private final Ressource ressource = new Ressource();


@Autowired
private IRessourceService ressourceService;

public RessourceBean(String nom, String prenom, String matricule, String mail, Date dateEntree, String telephone) {
    super();
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;
    this.matricule = matricule;
    this.mail = mail;
    this.dateEntree = dateEntree;
    this.telephone=telephone;
}

public RessourceBean() {
    super();
}

public void save(){

    System.out.println("==============> begin ");
    System.out.println(" Nom ==>" + getRessource().getNom() );
    System.out.println(" prenom ==>" + getRessource().getPrenom() );
    System.out.println(" telephone ==>" + getRessource().getTelephone());
    System.out.println(" MAT ==>" + getRessource().getMatricule() );
    System.out.println(" DAte ==>" + getRessource().getDateEntree() );
    System.out.println(" mail ==>" + getRessource().getMail() );
    System.out.println("==============> end ");

    ressourceService.addRessource(ressource);
    System.out.println("==============> insertion finished ");
}



public String getTelephone() {
    return telephone;
}

public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
    this.telephone = telephone;
}

public IRessourceService getRessourceService() {
    return ressourceService;
}

public void setRessourceService(IRessourceService ressourceService) {
    this.ressourceService = ressourceService;
}

public Ressource getRessource() {
    return ressource;
}

public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public String getPrenom() {
    return prenom;
}

public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
    this.prenom = prenom;
}

public String getMatricule() {
    return matricule;
}

public void setMatricule(String matricule) {
    this.matricule = matricule;
}

public String getMail() {
    return mail;
}

public void setMail(String mail) {
    this.mail = mail;
}

public Date getDateEntree() {
    return dateEntree;
}

public void setDateEntree(Date dateEntree) {
    this.dateEntree = dateEntree;
}
```

}

Here is implementation for my service RessourceServiceImpl

```
package ma.controle.gestion.service.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import ma.controle.gestion.dao.IRessourceDao;
import ma.controle.gestion.modele.Ressource;


@Transactional
@Service("ressourceService")
public class RessourceServiceImpl implements IRessourceDao {

@Autowired
private IRessourceDao ressourceDao;


@Override
public void addRessource(Ressource ressource) {
    System.out.println("Service Baby");
    ressourceDao.addRessource(ressource);
}


public IRessourceDao getRessourceDao() {
    return ressourceDao;
}


public void setRessourceDao(IRessourceDao ressourceDao) {
    this.ressourceDao = ressourceDao;
}


}
```

and here is the implementation of my dao RessourceDaoImpl

```
package ma.controle.gestion.dao.impl;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import ma.controle.gestion.dao.IRessourceDao;
import ma.controle.gestion.modele.Ressource;

@Repository("ressourceDao")
public class RessourceDaoImpl implements IRessourceDao {


@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory; 

@Override
public void addRessource(Ressource ressource) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(ressource);
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
}
```

Comment: whre exactly is `RessourceBean.java: line 62`? is it `System.out.println(" Nom ==>" + getRessource().getNom() );`?

Comment: @JohnnyAW Hello thank you for your reply line : 62 its `ressourceService.addRessource(ressource);` In the save method

Comment: I found the solution on this post, thank you for your attention and your time
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387993/spring-jsf-integration-how-to-inject-a-spring-component-service-in-jsf-managed

Answer (score 1):

I guess your @Autowired `resourceService` is not being set, since you expect it to be `IRessourceService`, but you are providing:

```
@Service("ressourceService")
public class RessourceServiceImpl implements IRessourceDao
```

so the bean container can't pick it up, change your Autowired annotation to:

```
@Autowired
private IRessourceDao ressourceService;
```

Comment: it was a error RessourceServiceImpl must implement IRessourceSerivce i changed this line but the error stil appear

Comment: same error? Make sure `RessourceServiceImpl`-class is in a package, that is being picked up by Annotation processing. Can you post your application initialization log? Maybe there is some error, showing @Autowired not being set. Btw. update your code in the question

Comment: there is no other problemsRessourceServiceImpl class in in a package and here is log for ContextLoader 

`Infos: Overriding bean definition for bean 'ressourceDao': replacing [Generic bean: class [ma.controle.gestion...`
`Infos: Overriding bean definition for bean 'ressourceService': replacing [Generic bean: class [ma.controle.gestion.service.impl.RessourceServiceImpl]; scope=singleton;...`

Comment: I found the solution on this post, thank you for your attention and your time
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387993/spring-jsf-integration-how-to-inject-a-spring-component-service-in-jsf-managed