# injecting jsf beans in a spring mvc manner

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2

I want to inject JSF beans using Spring annotations.

I want my app to use JSF components and also Primefaces (on frontend). But also, on backend I want to have repositories, services and managed beans and to be able to inject a @Repository into a @Servive, and also a @Service into a bean @Named and @ViewScoped.

For example:

**Persistence layer:**

```
public interface UserRepository {
  List<User> getAllUsers();
}

@Repository
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository{

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("select u from User u").getResultList();
    }
}
```

**Business layer:**

```
public interface UserService {
    List<User> getAllUsers();
}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.getAllUsers();
    }
}
```

**Presentation layer:**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class UserManagement{

    @Autowired
    protected UserService userService;
    protected List<User> users;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        if(users.isEmpty()) {
            users = userService.getAllUsers();
        }
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users= users;
    }
}
```

And, as view let say I have an xhtml with jsf components. For example, I have a dataTable in which I'll store all users.

I was reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387993/spring-jsf-integration-how-to-inject-a-spring-component-service-in-jsf-managed/18388289) but it is not that clear.

Comment: What is not clear in the other post?

Comment: First of all, looks like you're mixing up CDI, JSF and Spring annotations. Pick up one. If you mix those annotations you might have problems