# Can we integrate JSF 2.0 + Spring 4.2.X + Spring Security 4.2.X

Tags: spring-security, jsf-2

I would like to know can we integrate Spring security 4.2.X with JSF 2.0. I am facing issue with JSP pring security tags for role wise access. If yes please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with mixing JSF and Spring as long as you do things right, aka not mixing your beans.

Check in this post [Spring JSF integration: how to inject a Spring component/service in JSF managed bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387993/spring-jsf-integration-how-to-inject-a-spring-component-service-in-jsf-managed) , the answer from BalusC, it will probably help you.

Comment: Better refer OP to his original post.

Comment: I cant comment yet coz no 50 rep but wanted to help :/

Comment: Sorry, I always forget that. You can gain 50 rep quickly by editing/improving existing questions and/or answers. But can't you flag questions as duplicates either. Then you could have flagged it as a dup of the post refer to

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to integrate Spring Security with JSF using XML configuration. I am able to integrate Spring with JSF but my target is to integrate Spring Security also. The Versions i need are Spring 4.2.x and Spring Security 4.2.x