# i can't reach my method with primefaces ajax

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

i have an issue with my project, i'm using spring , jsf and primefaces, the problem is when i wish to call a method with ajax request, i can't and i have no error message to help me found the problem this is my first configuration with spring and jsf with annotations.
help me please .

my configuration:

```
     @Configuration
     @ComponentScan
     @EnableTransactionManagement
     public class AppConfig {
 @Bean
 public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306   /carouzetDb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&   useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
         dataSource.setUsername("root");
       dataSource.setPassword("root");
       return dataSource;
         }

private  Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

    return hibernateProperties;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.crouzet.carouzetroject.entities");
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
            = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

}

```
    public class MvcContentInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {  
       AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  
    ctx.register(AppConfig.class);  
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);    
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

  }  
  }
```

jsf configuration :
faces-config.xml

```
     <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
     <faces-config version="2.2"
          xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
   <application>
    <el-resolver>
         org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
    </application>
    <render-kit>
   <renderer>
    <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
     <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.FileUploadRenderer</renderer-type>
    <renderer-class>com.crouzet.carouzetroject.FileUploadRenderer</renderer-class>
   </renderer>
  </render-kit>
    </faces-config>
```

and here is the example where i call my method:

```
   @ManagedBean(name = "helloBean")
   @ViewScoped
   @Component
    public class HelloBean {
 List<Salarie> salaries;
 List<Categorie> categories;
 List<Poste> postes;
 Production production;
 Categorie selectedCat;

 @Autowired
 private CategorieDAO categorieDAO;
 @Autowired
 private SalarieDAO salarieDAO;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    categories=categorieDAO.allCategories();
            System.out.println("==========>>>FROM INIT"+categories.size());


}

public void actualiser(){
     categories=categorieDAO.allCategories();
}
public void listeDesSalaries(){
    System.out.println("========AAAAAAAAAAAAAA========>>>>");
    if(selectedCat!=null)
    salaries=salarieDAO.salariesParCategorie(selectedCat);
}

public List<Salarie> getSalaries() {
    return salaries;
}

public void setSalaries(List<Salarie> salaries) {
    this.salaries = salaries;
}

public List<Categorie> getCategories() {
    return categories;
}

public void setCategories(List<Categorie> categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
}

public List<Poste> getPostes() {
    return postes;
}

public void setPostes(List<Poste> postes) {
    this.postes = postes;
}

public Production getProduction() {
    return production;
}

public void setProduction(Production production) {
    this.production = production;
}

public Categorie getSelectedCat() {
    return selectedCat;
}

public void setSelectedCat(Categorie selectedCat) {
    this.selectedCat = selectedCat;
}

}
```

and here is my page

```
       <h:form>
         <p:commandButton action="#{helloBean.actualiser()}"  value="Actualiser"  update="mesListes"/>
         <p:panelGrid id="mesListes" columns="2">
             <p:outputLabel  value="Ligne de fabrication"/>
             <p:selectOneMenu  id="categori" value="#{helloBean.selectedCat}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{helloBean.categories}" var="cat" itemLabel="#{cat.nom}" itemValue="#{cat}" />
        <p:ajax listener="#{helloBean.listeDesSalaries()}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
         </p:panelGrid>

     </h:form>
```

Comment: Start reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387993/spring-jsf-integration-how-to-inject-a-spring-component-service-in-jsf-managed

Comment: And does using a plain `h:selectonemenu` and `f:ajax` work?