# How to invoke Service Class Interface in CDI bean

Tags: spring, jsf, cdi

We are planning to change Managed Beans to CDI beans. We used below code to invoke Service class in managed Bean.

```
@ManagedProperty("#{userService}")
private UserService userService;  and setter method
```

For CDI bean, I replaced @ManagedProperty with @inject as shown below, and it is throwing following exception.

```
@SessionScoped
@Named
public class LoginController implements Serializable {
   @Inject
   private UserService userService;
```

}

```
org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: Passivation capable beans must satisfy passivation capable dependencies.
```

UserService is a plain interface with unimplemented methods and UserServiceImpl implements UserService interface. Please see below:

```
public interface UserService {
 public List<User> getUserList();   
}

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
  private UserDao userDao;

  public List<User> getUserList() {
        return userDao.getUserList();
 }
}
```

Please let me know me how to invoke service interface in CDI beans?

Comment: Is UserService a CDI-Bean either with @Named annotation? And you didn't add the full exception with trace.

Comment: @selaron : UserService is a plain interface with unimplemented methods and UserServiceImpl implements UserService interface.

Comment: Editing the post to include details is perfectly right. THis is still not the full exception stack trace but better than before.

Comment: Who is managing the userService bean? If it should be a CDI bean, UserServiceImpl should be annotated @Named (and appropriate scope). And/Or it must be serializable because your  LoginController is SessionScopend and therefore needs to be serializable plus all fields need to be Serializable.

Comment: Looks like this is a SpringFramework bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading BalusC's answer on [Spring JSF integration: how to inject a Spring component/service in JSF managed bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18388289/865107) tells me it is supposed to be supported that your Spring bean `userService` should be injected into your CDI bean `LoginController`.

But your `UserServiceImpl` is not `Serializable` which in CDI context means it is not **passivation capable**.

This is also what your Exception tells.

So either make your LoginController `@RequestScoped` instead of `@SessionScoped` so itself and `@Inject`ed children do not require to be passivation capable (aka `Serializable`).
Or make your `UserServiceImpl` and DAO Implementations `Serializable` (which imho is somewhat odd?).